# Rails 3 controller - if question record doesn't have a corresponding answer record, create one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've worked with rails 2... but i'm still a rails 3 noob/disaster.

@questions is a set of questions from the questions table. I need to make sure that each question has a corresponding answer record in the answers table. If one does not exist, i need to create one with the default value of zero. In my controller i have the following:

```
# create records for answers that do not exist yet
@questions.each do |q|
  a = Answer.where(q.id = Answer.question_id and current_user.id = Answer.user_id )
  if a.nil?
    Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `question_id'
```

I'm going on vacation and taking the 4th edition of Agile Web Development with Rails (don't tell my wife :=]) Any help you can offer here would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
@questions.each do |q|
  a = Answer.where(:question_id => q.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
  if a.empty?
    Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)
  end
end
```

But it can be refactored as

```
@questions.each do |q|
  q.answers.create(:score => 0) unless q.answers.where(:user => current_user).any?
end
```

**EDIT**

As far as you don't understand what is going on here: you should or `create` or `save` your object:

```
answer = Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)
answer.save
```

or

```
Answer.create(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)
```

Comment: @fl00r, thanks. Unfortunately, there is no error msg, but "Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)" is not adding any records.

Comment: @fl00r, thanks again. i changed it to "Answer.create(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0, :user_id => current_user.id )" and its still not creating the new records. BTW the refactored version produces, "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'answers.user' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`user` = 1 AND (`answers`.question_id = 4)". Am now trying variations of it.

Comment: Error is because you haven't got `belongs_to :user` association in your Answer model. And I see my mistake. I'll update my answer

Comment: it should be `a.empty?` or `a.any?` not a `a.nil?`

Comment: @fl00r, q.answers.create(:score => 0, :user_id => current_user.id ) unless q.answers.where(:user_id => current_user.id ).any? works!

Comment: `q.answers.create(:score => 0, :user_id => current_user.id )` of course it works, but you'd better add `belongs_to` association

Answer (score 1):

The activerecord query syntax is incorrect. It should be something like this -

```
@questions.each do |q|
  a = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", q.id, current_user.id )
  if a.nil?
    Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)
  end
end
```

Look at this post for more details http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, there is no error msg, but "Answer.new(:question_id => q.id, :score => 0)" is not adding any records.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have added a `has_many` relationship to `Question`, you could do this

```
@questions.each do |q|
  if q.answers.empty?
    q.answers.create! :score => 0, :user => current_user
  end
end
```

It iterates over the questions, checks to see if the question has answers, and adds one with score zero and user `current_user`, if it is empty. It also will raise an error if the save fails (that's what adding `!` to `create` or `save` does).

You will have to ensure your models know about the relationships for this to work:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```